# Proof of dynamic programming solution for Leetcode 818: Racecar

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, proof, correctness, proof-of-correctness

The problem is as follows:

**Problem:**

"Your car starts at position 0 and speed +1 on an infinite number line. Your car can go into negative positions. Your car drives automatically according to a sequence of instructions 'A' (accelerate) and 'R' (reverse):

When you get an instruction 'A', your car does the following:

- position += speed
- speed *= 2

When you get an instruction 'R', your car does the following:

- If your speed is positive then speed = -1
- otherwise speed = 1
- Your position stays the same.

For example, after commands "AAR", your car goes to positions 0 --> 1 --> 3 --> 3, and your speed goes to 1 --> 2 --> 4 --> -1.

Given a target position target, return the length of the shortest sequence of instructions to get there."

Source: https://leetcode.com/problems/race-car/description/

**Proposed DP solution:**

Let DP[i] be the number of instructions needed to travel a distance "i" in the right-hand direction.

Then DP[0] = 0

For our update rule, there are 3 cases.

1. First reach some j < i without reversing, then reverse and travel some distance to k < j. Finally, reverse again and use the previously solved DP[i-k]
2. First, reach some j > i without reversing, then reverse and use the previously solved DP[j-i]
3. We can reach i without reversing

According to the above update rules, we can solve from DP[0] to DP[i] to obtain our solution.

**Issue:**

This seems to be the widely accepted DP solution to this problem, but I have yet to find a satisfying proof, or even any proof at all, that this algorithm is correct.

For example, how could one prove that the optimal way to traverse a distance "i" isn't to immediately reverse and go to some a < 0, then reverse and travel to some j > i, and finally reverse again and use DP[j-i]?

Or how could one prove that the optimal way to traverse a distance "i" isn't to overshoot to a distance j > 2i, and then reverse and travel a distance 2i - j > i, which is a subproblem that would not yet have been solved?

Many "proofs" I come across make vague statements such as "it should be clear that you don't want to go overshoot to j > 2i" and so on which is less than rigorous.

**My current thoughts:**

At the moment, I can at least put forth what I think is a valid proof to prove that we would never want to first reverse to some a < 0, then reverse to some j > i, and then make our way back to DP[j-i].

My proof for this is that in this case, we would reverse a total of 3 times. Rather than do this, we could simply make our way to j + a without reversing, then reverse once and go to j, then reverse *twice* (reverse once to set speed to 0, and then reverse again to point back towards i) and go to i. I believe this should result in the same amount of steps in the end.

However, I still have trouble proving why we would never overshoot to some j > 2i and then make our way back to i?

If anyone could provide a proof for this solution, that would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is less about programming and more about providing a mathematical proof.  Suggest this question should be asked on [Mathmatics](https://math.stackexchange.com/).  Be sure to verify proper format and structure of question for this site.

Comment: @itprorh66 this question is tagged appropriately, and a large part of programming is knowing that the algorithm you're writing is actually correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why we would never overshoot to some j > 2i and then make our way back to i?

Well, how would we get there? Call the vector (the last jump) that led there `v`.

If we issued `v` from a position after `i`, that would be redundant as we can use the recurrence we defined for `j > i` without the `v` jump.

And if we issued `v` from before `i` to get to a distance greater than `2*i`, it's simple: we can't. Aside from `i = 2^p - 1`, which has a trivial solution, we cannot achieve a magnitude greater than `i / 2`, necessary to leap farther than `i`, before `i`.

(Note that the interpretation of `j > i` is taken from the recurrence explanation at https://leetcode.com/problems/race-car/solutions/124326/summary-of-the-bfs-and-dp-solutions-with-intuitive-explanation)

---

We can prove that going below position 0 is unnecessary by observing that any sequence `s` starting at 0 and ending at some lowest point `l` below zero will have a subsequent sequence `s'` that starts by going higher and takes it all the way to `i`, never going as low as `l`. We can switch the order so that `s'` is executed first and then `s`. There are two cases, depending on the direction `s'` ends in.

One case is when `s'` ends going left (note that the drawing makes the rightmost point of `s` and `s'` the same as their visual right end but the rightmost point in their sequence could be farther):

```
<--------0------------->s
-----------<-->s' (ending <-)
l          i

         0----------<-->s'
           <--------x------------->s
           i
```

When `s'` ends going right, define `V` as the first section of `s` until it first reverses to go below zero, and define `U` as the first vector of `s'` (we defined it already as going right).

If `V`'s magnitude is smaller than or equal to `U`s, merge `V` with `s'` and apply `V` again at the end:

```
           Vector V going right
<--------0--V-->s
U------->----------->s' (ending ->)
l                   i

         0------->----------->s'
              <--------x--V-->s
              ---V-->
                    i
```

If `V`'s magnitude is greater than `U`s, apply `V` instead of `U` and apply `U` at the end:

```
Vector V going right
<--------0-V--->s
U-->---------------->s' (ending ->)

l                   i
           V
         0-V--->---------------->s'
                 <--------0-V--->s
                 U-->
                    i
```